# Which is the appropriate data structure?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I need a Java data structure that has:

- fast (O(1)) insertion
- fast removal
- fast (O(1)) `max()` function

What's the best data structure to use?

HashMap would almost work, but using `java.util.Collections.max()` is at least O(n) in the size of the map.  TreeMap's insertion and removal are too slow.

Any thoughts?

Comment: and an off day it should be.. It's Sunday, and it's Easter ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O(1) insertion and O(1) `max()` are mutually exclusive together with the fast removal point.

A O(1) insertion collection won't have O(1) `max` as the collection is unsorted. A O(1) `max` collection has to be sorted, thus the insert is O(n). You'll have to bite the bullet and choose between the two. In both cases however, the removal should be equally fast.

If you can live with slow removal, you could have a variable saving the current highest element, compare on insert with that variable, max and insert should be O(1) then. Removal will be O(n) then though, as you have to find a new highest element in the cases where the removed element was the highest.

Comment: Ah hah!  Of course!  Thanks for the key observation about O(1) max requiring an a-priori sorted list.  I'll re-think my requirements!

Comment: You can combine more data structures together to get O(1) max in most cases. Please see my answer, if you want.

Comment: To nitpick: _Has_ to be sorted is incorrect. For instance if one could arrange them so that each element is no more than 100 away from it's actual position, then it is still O(1).

Comment: Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: @Femaref Moron is right: here's an algorithm for max() in a data structure where each element is within 100 spots of where it would be in a list sorted max to min:
1. max = first element of list
2. iterate over exactly 100 elements (or the size of the list, if it's smaller). For each element,
  2.1 If element is > max, max = element
Since this always takes 100 steps, no matter how large the list, the algorithm is O(1).

Comment: Actually the point about max() needing a sorted data structure is not entirely correct. A max heap is the first example that comes to my mind, although that still doesn't fulfill all properties (since those are really impossible)

Comment: @Voo: max requires at least semi-ordered data structure, like the heap. at my answer I proved why max,del,add cannot be all done in O(1), you are welcome to take a look.

Answer (score 5):

If you can have O(log n) insertion and removal, you can have O(1) max value with a TreeSet or a PriorityQueue. O(log n) is pretty good for most applications.

Answer (score 4):

If you accept that O(log n) is still "fast" even though it isn't "fast (O(1))", then some kinds of heap-based priority queue will do it. See the [comparison table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) for different heaps you might use.

Note that Java's library [PriorityQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) isn't very exciting, it only guarantees O(n) `remove(Object)`.

For heap-based queues "remove" can be implemented as "decreaseKey" followed by "removeMin", provided that you reserve a "negative infinity" value for the purpose. And since it's the max you want, invert all mentions of "min" to "max" and "decrease" to "increase" when reading the article...

Answer (score 2):

you cannot have O(1) removal+insertion+max

**proof:**

assume you could, let's call this data base D

given an array A: 

1. insert all elements in A to D.

2. create empty linked list L

3. while D is not empty:

3.1. x<-D.max(); D.delete(x); --all is O(1) - assumption

3.2 L.insert_first(x) -- O(1)

4. return L

 in here we created a sorting algorithm which is O(n), but it is proven to be impossible! sorting is known as omega(nlog(n)). contradiction! thus, D cannot exist.

Comment: n is both O(n) and Omega(n). Did you mean Omega(nlogn)? Even then, you are forgetting a crucial point: the underlying model in which sorting is Omega(nlogn): The algebraic decision tree model. Using hash tables etc is outside that model, if I remember correctly. IF you are only using comparisons to find the max, then yes, Omega(nlogn) compares are required and hence such a structure won't be possible.

Comment: @Moron: thanks for the correction, it is of course omega(nlogn). because we do need the max, a nlogn comparisons are needed, and thus the theorem applies here

Comment: I like the gist of your proof, but unfortunately the contradiction doesn't work -- an algorithm can be both O(n) and Omega(n) (and in fact that's the definition of Theta(n))

Comment: Peyton, don't confuse algorithms with problems. Sorting is Omega(n log n) and we have O(n log n) sorting algorithms. But you can prove a problem is Omega(something) while the best algorithm discovered so far is O(more that something).

Comment: @Gia: I believe Peyton is referring to an older version of this answer.

Comment: Giacomo, thanks for the correction.  Professor Joe Traub will be furious with me tomorrow for muddling that!  In any case, given amit's correction, I retract my statement.  Glad we've straightened this thread out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very skeptical that TreeMap's log(n) insertion and deletion are too slow--log(n) time is practically constant with respect to most real applications.  Even with a 1,000,000,000 elements in your tree, if it's balanced well you will only perform log(2, 1000000000)  = ~30 comparisons per insertion or removal, which is comparable to what any other hash function would take.

Comment: Seems unlikely to me that clever people would have troubled themselves to invent and prove the properties of things like Fibonacci heaps, if a BST was adequate for all purposes.

Comment: Giacomo -- my bad, I meant constant.  Fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Such a data structure would be awesome and, as far as I know, **doesn't exist**. Others pointed this.

But you can go beyond, if you don't care making all of this a bit more complex.

If you can "waste" some memory and some programming efforts, you can use, at the same time, *different data structures*, combining the pro's of each one.

For example I needed a **sorted** data structure but wanted to have **O(1)** lookups ("is the element X in the collection?"), not O(log n). I combined a **TreeMap** with an **HashMap** (which is not really O(1) but it is *almost* when it's not too full and the hashing function is good) and I got really good results.

For your specific case, I would go for a dynamic combination between an HashMap and a *custom* helper data structure. I have in my mind something very complex (hash map + variable length priority queue), but I'll go for a simple example. Just keep all the stuff in the HashMap, and then use a special field (`currentMax`) that only contains the `max` element in the map. When you `insert()` in your combined data structure, if the element you're going to insert is > than the current `max`, then you do `currentMax <- elementGoingToInsert` (and you insert it in the HashMap).

When you remove an element from your combined data structure, you check if it is equal to the `currentMax` and if it is, you remove it from the map (that's normal) and you have to find the new `max` (in O(n)). So you do `currentMax <- findMaxInCollection()`.

If the `max` doesn't change very frequently, that's damn good, believe me.

However, don't take anything for granted. You have to struggle a bit to find the best combination between different data structures. Do your tests, learn how frequently `max` changes. Data structures aren't easy, and you can make a difference if you really work combining them instead of finding a magic one, that doesn't exist. :)

Cheers

Comment: "doesn't exist" is true only in certain (restricted) models.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a degenerate answer. I noted that you hadn't specified what you consider "fast" for deletion; if O(n) is fast then the following will work. Make a class that wraps a HashSet; maintain a reference to the maximum element upon insertion. This gives the two constant time operations. For deletion, if the element you deleted is the maximum, you have to iterate through the set to find the maximum of the remaining elements.

This may sound like it's a silly answer, but in some practical situations (a generalization of) this idea could actually be useful. For example, you can still maintain the *five* highest values in constant time upon insertion, and whenever you delete an element that happens to occur in that set you remove it from your list-of-five, turning it into a list-of-four etcetera; when you add an element that falls in that range, you can extend it back to five. If you typically add elements much more frequently than you delete them, then it may be very rare that you need to provide a maximum when your list-of-maxima is empty, and you can restore the list of five highest elements in linear time in that case.

Answer (score 0):

As already explained: for the general case, no. However, if your range of values are limited, you can use a counting sort-like algorithm to get O(1) insertion, and on top of that a linked list for moving the max pointer, thus achieving O(1) max and removal.